# How can I correctly load ImageMagick within CakePHP 3, or change settings?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to use ImageMagick inside a controller for CakePHP 3, in order to resize and convert images. However on attempting, the system has been generating an error

Error: Class 'App\Controller\Imagick' not found

I know this looks like it is caused by Imagick not being present, however this is occurring inside the load test for Imagick - it appears to be entirely on CakePHP 3's settings.

```
    if (extension_loaded('imagick'))
    {
        $AlteredImage = new Imagick($image);
    }
```

What do I need to change with CakePHP in order to get this to work? Alternatively, could this be related to php.ini settings?

Comment: 1. Install ImageMagic 2. copy imagick.so to the `\php\ext`  folder. Amend `php.ini` and add `extension=imagick.so`

Comment: ImageMagic is installed. imagick.so is in the correct folder. No reaction so far other then the above result.

Comment: `\Imagick`... **http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php**

Comment: This appears to be the working answer - could you create one?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm)'s comment,

> \Imagick... php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

Cakephp work with namespaces so you need to use `\Imagick...` to reference all Imagick functions as a fallback to global function/constant.

Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php for more info.